# Error trying to store objects in a numpy 2D array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import B as b

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__array = np.empty((4,4), dtype=object)

    def __create_subimages(self):
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        l = 0
        position = 0

        while i != self.__rows_quotient * self.__rows:
            sub_image = b.B(self.__image[i:i + self.__rows_quotient, j:j + self.__cols_quotient], position)
            np.append(self.__array, sub_image)
            if j == self.__cols_quotient * (self.__cols - 1):
                j = 0
                i += self.__rows_quotient
            else:
                j += self.__cols_quotient
            if l == len(self.__subimages[0]) - 1:
                l = 0
                k += 1
            else:
                l += 1

            position += 1
            misc.imshow(self.__subimages[0][0].get_image())
```

And this other class:

```
class B():

        def __init__(self, image, position):
            self.__image = image
            self.__position = position

        def get_image(self):
            return self.__image
```

SO what I'm trying is to store objects `B` to the numpy array `__subimages` and then show the image it contents which I return with `get_image` in `B` class

However, I'm getting the following error output:

```
misc.imshow(self.__subimages[0][0].get_image())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_image'
```

Why is it Nontype? It's supposed to be a `B` object which has a method to return an array.

Please help :(

Comment: Is the code you show supposed to be complete?  I don't see where `__subimages` is initialized in the class `A`.

Comment: It's __array sorry, I modified it already. All I wanna do is to add objects from B in a 2D array

Comment: `np.append` does not work in-place.  It returns a new array.  Shouldn't the line `np.append(self.__array, sub_image)` be something like `self.__array[i, j] = sub_image`?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice append returns another array. I just did this and it worked!: self.__array = np.append(self.__array, sub_image) THANK YOU VERY MUCH!